# How to Import jar file into an Android project?

Tags: android

I am trying to use the loopj library in my Android project. In the project home page it says "Download the latest .jar file from github and place it in your Android apps libs folder". I did that!

As indicated in the documentation of the loopj I try to import it using the following

```
import com.loopj.android.http;
```

and nothing  happens. It is not even coming up in intellisense.

Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: are you using android studio or eclipse?

Comment: have you tried fixing the build path errors around it ?

Comment: I am using Android Studio. There are no build path errors. I added the loopj file in the app/libs directory.

Comment: check if it helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607552/How-to-add-external-library-file-in-Android-Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `build.gradle` file add your jar such as below then rebuild.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that still it does not recognize the AsyncHttpClient class.

Comment: sync your gradle, if it's success, you'll see this small arrow indicator left to your jar file and you'll be able to see its classes etc, that means that you added it successfully.

Comment: Actually after adding it to dependencies as you suggested I ran the app and it works. Although for some reason Android Studio shows wiggly red lines under AsyncHttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

into the `build.gradle` file add the following::

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    compile files('libs/<your jar's name here>')
}
```

Rebuid your project or Run `./gradlew assemble`. This should compile the project with the library.

Answer (score 0):

To let the Android Studio load all of your jar files by itself automatically, just write this line in the dependency section

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This will help android studio to load all of your jar files available in libs folder.